# jQuery not permitting removeClass

Tags: jquery, removeclass

```
var className = "Chiropractor";

var itemsToToggle = "."+className+"Toggle";
console.log(itemsToToggle);
find(itemsToToggle).removeClass("show").addClass("hide");


returns:
.ChiropractorToggle
TypeError: Object #<error> has no method 'removeClass'
```

I can do console.log(itemsToToggle); and it will return the elements I need, but no idea why it wont allow me to use removeClass method on it.

Comment: Is `find()` a method that returns a jQuery object or something. What is that code?

Comment: Because whatever `find(itemstoToggle)` does isn't returning a jQuery object.

Comment: Replace `find` with `$`?

Comment: oh, derp. yep, that's it. not sure why I put find instead of $

Comment: Accept one of the answers if they answered your question please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use

```
$(itemsToToggle).removeClass("show").addClass("hide");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `find` doesn't return a `jQuery` object, use the following code.

```
$(itemsToToggle).removeClass("show").addClass("hide");
^
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no `find` function in Javascript. jQuery's `.find` is a method that must be applied to a jQuery object:

```
$(someSelector).find(itemsToToggle).removeClass("show").addClass("hide");
```

If you want to search the entire DOM, not just start from some selector, you can use `$(itemsToToggle)` instead of `.find()`.